# Change python print flush rate

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to change the rate that Python flushes content to the console? I know it is possible to add `flush = True` to the print command (at least in latest version of Python 3) to ensure the content is printed, however, is there a global setting that can be changed so that content is committed to the screen more often, or after a set amount of time.

(essentially, i want to make content be flushed more quickly, or at least in periodic intervals, but not every single print statement which would slow down the code).

Comment: Override `print` function and add a counter, calling builtin `print` with or without `flush` depending on the current value in the counter?

Comment: there is `-u` option but that will make it all unbuffered so probably not what you want, outside of that maybe something like @tobias_k suggested but not sure if worth it...

Comment: also you may want to consider different/faster terminal as this is likely bigger culprit than whatever Python does

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this toy example:

```
import time

print_interval = 1 # 1 second
last_print_time = time.time()

for i in range(100):
    time.sleep(0.1) # An arbitrary time-consuming task
    now = time.time()
    if now - last_print_time >= print_interval:
        print('something', flush=True)
        last_print_time = now
    else:
        print('somethine else', flush=False)
```